# Get fields of stdClass object one by one

Tags: php, stdclass

I am getting response from SMS API call like below

```
stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 3 
   [batch_id] => 289728321 
   [cost] => 2
   [num_messages] => 2
   [message] => stdClass Object ( 
       [num_parts] => 1
       [sender] => TXTLCL
       [content] => This is test message from abc
   ) 
   [receipt_url] => 
   [custom] => 
   [messages] => Array ( 
       [0] => stdClass Object (
              [id] => 1172603746 [recipient] => 919796736174 )
       [1] => stdClass Object ( 
              [id] => 1172603747 [recipient] => 919858566712)
   )
   [status] => success 
)
```

The code which I am trying to tweak is like below

```
 if(count($this->capturedResponse) > 0)
 {
     foreach($this->capturedResponse as $response)
     { 
      $balance = $response[0];
      $batch_id = $response[1];
      ...
      }
 }
```

I am not able to separate the stdClass Object fields separately and put them in their corresponding variables.

Please Help !!!

Comment: Thanks everybody for answering... Please provide parsing for all the fields. as it is difficult for other fields like     [message] => stdClass Object ( 
       [num_parts] => 1
       [sender] => TXTLCL
       [content] => This is test message from abc
   )

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `->` to get element from object, so use like this

```
 $balance = $response->balance;
 $batch_id = $response->batch_id;
```

Instead

```
 $balance = $response[0];
 $batch_id = $response[1];
 ...
```

To get `content` of `message`

```
 $message = $response->message->content
```

Try yourself for `messages` by loop let us know if any problem

**Update**

```
$messagesObj = $response->messages;
$messagesArr = array();
foreach($messagesObj as $key=>$value){
   $messagesArr[] = $value->recipient;
}
$messages = implode(",",$messagesArr);
```

You will get `919796736174, 919858566712` in `$messages`

Comment: Please provide me for messages also because I have very limited messages balance and cannot do experiment...

Comment: @user2179026 : its array of object how to you want to get this ? I means in which form ? Its multiple

Comment: I just want to get their recipient numbers from messages object and with comma seperated

Comment: thats I am saying it a multiple how do you want in array or in string combined.

Comment: I want it to be string like $recipientNumbers="919796736174, 919858566712"

Comment: Now I tried the code... it is throwing error message Undefined property: stdClass::$num_messages ... Please help... i have low sms balance

Comment: How did you tried ? it should be like `$response->num_messages`

Comment: I tried like $response->num_messages; it throws error

Comment: foreach($this->capturedResponse as $response)
                { 
                    $this->sendSuccessCount = $response->num_messages;
                }

Comment: Check by isset for each element as `$num_messages = isset($response->num_messages)?$response->num_messages:'';`

Comment: This error occur if any this element is not present in any iteration

Comment: Now it is always displaying 0 despite having some values... please check ur code...

Comment: are you sure you are not replacing/ orverwriting  with previous value , try `echo $num_messages;`after getting value in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
 $balance = $response->balance;
 $batch_id = $response->batch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to JSON-encode your object and then decode it back to an array:

```
$capturedResponse = (object) (array(
   'balance' => 1,
   'batch_id' => 289728321,
   'cost' => 2,
   'num_messages' => 2,
   'message' => (object) (array(
       'num_parts' => 1
   ))
));

$array = json_decode(json_encode($capturedResponse), True);
echo $array['balance'];
```